# Converting numeric series to ts object with frequency = 7 for STL function

Tags: r, time-series, frequency

I have a very small data set of 63 obs in a data frame.  I want to convert it to a ts object so that I can do seasonal and trend decomposition using stl() with a s.window of 7. The odd thing is when I coerce the data with a frequency of 7 for weekly seasonal effects, the ts never sets it as 7, but 1??  Frequency 7 is needed for weekly periodicity. I don't get an error or warning, and I can't find any reference out there that could explain this behavior.

Actual data set:

```
x <- c(77, 19, 13, 46, 302, 676, 1311, 1479, 1884, 1941, 2601, 2603, 2812,
2570, 2602, 2459, 2623, 2672, 2710, 2780, 2945, 2711, 2645, 2077, 2842,
2990, 3205, 2956, 2823, 2421, 1302, 1180, 2539, 2087, 2610, 2726, 3129,
4716, 2848, 3152, 2869, 2894, 2763, 3011, 2579, 2610, 2724, 2832, 2373,  
2412, 2269, 2488, 1958, 2161, 2574, 2818, 2164, 2973, 2840, 2762, 2613, 
1896, 3180)

df <- data.frame(x)
xts <- as.ts(df$x, start=c(2017,1), frequency=7, calendar=T)
xts
```

Results

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 63 
Frequency = 1
[1]   77   19   13   46  302  676 1311 1479 1884 1941 2601 2603 2812 2570 
2602 2459 2623 2672 2710 2780 2945 2711
[23] 2645 2077 2842 2990 3205 2956 2823 2421 1302 1180 2539 2087 2610 2726 
3129 4716 2848 3152 2869 2894 2763 3011
[45] 2579 2610 2724 2832 2373 2412 2269 2488 1958 2161 2574 2818 2164 2973 
2840 2762 2613 1896 3180
```

Comment: Use `ts` rather than `as.ts`.

Comment: `calendar` is also not a parameter of `ts` (maybe you are looking at `print.ts`?).

Comment: `xts <- ts(df$x, start=c(2017,1), frequency=7)`